# Taking the total number of lines from a file reading process

Tags: python

```
fileinput = open('tweets.txt', 'r')

for line in fileinput:

   lines = line.lower()
```

from this how can I take the whole lines and not only the last?

Comment: you overwrite the "lines" every time with the latest one.

Comment: Vote to close. There are answers to **your** previous very similar question already, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154787/reading-lines-from-a-file-using-python/14154889#14154889

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will give you a list:

```
fileinput = open('tweets.txt', 'r')
lines = [line.lower() for line in fileinput]
```

If this is not what you're looking for, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: newLine = re.sub('[,]', '', lines)

Comment: What are you expecting `re.sub()` to do here? It works on a string, and you're giving it a list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the assignment operator `=`.

You need to change this to a `+=` but you will lose the new line character `\n`.

I would suggest opening a list like this:

```
fileinput = open('tweets.txt', 'r')

lines = []

for line in fileinput:

   lines.append(line.lower())
```

Then you will have all lines in a list.

Regards
Joe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert all the lines:

```
fileinput = open("tweets.txt", "r")
lowered = [l.lower() for l in fileinput]
```